# How can a discontinuous function belong to $C_B^1(\Omega)$, the space of continuous functions $u$ with bounded derivatives?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, continuity

Let $\Omega = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ 0 < |x| < 1, \ 0 < y < 1\}$ and consider the function $u$ defined on $\Omega$ by (Sobolev Spaces by Adams, page 68, Example 3.10)
$$
u(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
1, \quad x > 0, \\
0, \quad x < 0.
\end{cases}
$$

On page 80 (item (iv)) of this book Adams says that this function belongs to $C_B^1(\Omega)$ which consists of function in $C^1(\Omega)$ such that $D^\alpha u$ is bounded for $0 \le \alpha \le 1$.

But this function is discontinuous at $x=0$ so how can it be an element of any space of continuous functions? Is this a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not a typo. The function is defined on two separate sets that are not path connected. On each set, it takes a constant value. Its maybe easier to see in 1D, this function is
$$ f: [-1,0)\cup (0,1] \to \mathbb R, \quad f(x) = \frac{\operatorname{sgn(x)+1}}2$$
$f$ is continuous (even $C^\infty$) on its domain, but there is no continuous extension to $[-1,1]$ (and certainly no $C^1$ extension).

Comment: Ah right, I had overlooked the function was not defined on $x = 0$. Do you know why he goes on to say that although the function is in $C_B^1(\Omega)$, it is not in $C^1(\bar \Omega)$, which is the closed subspace of $C_1^j(\Omega)$ consisting of functions have uniformly continuous derivatives up to order $1$  on $\Omega$? ..how can $C^1(\bar \Omega)$ even be a subspace of $C_B^1(\Omega)$ as $C^1(\bar \Omega)$ is defined on $\bar \Omega$ which is bigger than $\Omega$?

Comment: Nevermind, he says on page that 10 that this is an abuse of notation.

Comment: If you are continuous on a bigger set, then the restrictions(which are invisible by the abuse of notation you mentioned) to smaller sets are naturally also continuous. That is, the inclusions are reversed; $A \subset B$ implies $C^1_B(B) \subset C^1_B(A)$. As a quick check, you may want to note that the extreme case of continuous functions defined only at a point $C^0(\{0\})$ contains every function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. @eurocoder